# Maven raises errors when reading from external property file

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, devops, build-tools

I'm reading an external property file, and using it in a `pom.xml` file but its not reading value from properties file.

My property file looks like this:

```
name=C:\demo
```

Here is the code I've tried:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <files>
          <file>C:\test.properties</file>
        </files>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>src/main/resources/</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>${name}</directory>
            <include>test/**</include>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: hello. so either the file is not read or you are using the wrong property. Since there is no error message the file seems to be found and I assume the ${dir} property you use in your example is the one you want? But the property file example only contains name= so it would be ${name} in your pom file.

Comment: both i cross verified. still tis not working i tried with ${name} also

Comment: Try run maven with `-X` and see if there is more information in the debug log.